# How can I change the width/height of the macOS Look Up popup window?

Tags: macos, finder

It seems the macOS Look Up popup window size is default, and there is no obvious way to change that, however I need to change its width/height, make it wider, and I believe there must be some way to do that, like edit some system files ...

[image]

[image]

Comment: When you say "I need to change it", what is the problem that you are trying to address with the existing size?

Comment: @benwiggy You can actually edit the label of the dictionary(in the Dictionary app, right-click on name of the dictionary), thus, if the lable is too long it won't display correctly, you can try that

Comment: Does that not solve the problem -- make the label shorter, instead of making the popup wider?

Comment: @benwiggy No, it won't solve the problem, the label can not be shorter, thus, the popup must be wider, I would aprreciate it very much if you can help solve this

Comment: Can you show a screenshot of the popup with this very long Dictionary label?

Comment: @benwiggy Yes, added as request, as you can see, the labels has been truncated